# Avoid duplicates in RSpec and VCR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using VCR to make my specs much faster, like below:

```
RSpec.describe NewCollaborator, type: :service do
  let(:call) { described_class.new(user, repo).call }
  let(:user) { 'user@example.com' }
  let(:repo) { 'github-repo' }

  context 'when jira board is provided' do
    it 'create jira ticket with new user and github repo',
       :aggregate_failures, vcr: { cassette_name: 'new_collaborator' } do
      expect(call).to eq(true)
      expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:post, 'https://company_board.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue')
    end
  end
end
```

The thing is I've got pretty much the same specs body in over 5 places (the only difference is in cassette name because I need to use new request). Is there a way to not repeat the same code with VCR?

Sample of different specs with pretty much the same code:

```
RSpec.describe NewRepo, type: :service do
  let(:call) { described_class.new(user, repo).call }
  let(:user) { 'user@example.com' }
  let(:repo) { 'github-repo' }

  context 'when jira board is provided' do
    it 'create jira ticket of new repo',
       :aggregate_failures, vcr: { cassette_name: 'new_repo' } do
      expect(call).to eq(true)
      expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:post, 'https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

what about wrapping mutliple specs inside cassette?

```rb
VCR.use_cassette 'new_repo' do
  it 'create jira ticket of new repo' do
     ...
  end

  it 'create jira ticket of new repo' do
     ...
  end
end
```